# Set On End Edit Event from a Input Box (Text Mesh Pro) while runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I am programming a game in Unity, but I have problems with the On End Edit Event on a Input box from Text Mesh Pro. I need to define the event while runtime (in code). I have really no idea how to approch this.

Here is a picture from the event in the editor and I want it to connect to the PressedButton Method in the class PlayerConnectionManager:

[image: Here is a picture from the event in the editor]

Thaks for any kind of help!

Comment: So you want to select your gameObject (which have the OnEndEdit event) and set this event to specific script-function, Am I right? Can I suggest you to use delegates?

Comment: I want to select the gameobject and the script on it wich contains the method which should get fired when the On End Edit event gets raised

Comment: Your question is very confusing. What exactly you are trying to achieve here? Are you trying to call the `PlayerConnectionManager.PressedButton`? and the event is not raised? Or are you trying to pass some variables to the above method at runtime? Do you want to add different method at runtime instead of above one?

Comment: I try to achieve what you can see in the picture in code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that you need to call the PlayerConnectionManager.PressedButton at runtime and not via editor. If that's the case its quite easy. You just have to use addlistener. Here is a snippet.

```
public class TextMeshAdd : MonoBehaviour 
{
    //input field object
    public TMP_InputField tmpInputField;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        //Add a listener function here
        //Note: The function has to be of the type with parameter string
        tmpInputField.onEndEdit.AddListener(TextMeshUpdated);
    }

    public void TextMeshUpdated(string text) 
    {
        Debug.Log("Output string "  + text);
    }
}
```

Remember the function you are giving it should have a parameter with string. ie
`PlayerConnectionManager.PressedButton` should be of similer type mentioned above `TextMeshUpdated(string text)`. This will allow it callback the function on end at runtime.

Another thing you have to keep in mind is that if you are using the inputfield in some other place make sure to remove the old listener before adding new listener.
You can do it by using this
    `tmpInputField.onEndEdit.RemoveListener(TextMeshUpdated);`
or
    `tmpInputField.onEndEdit.RemoveAllListeners();`

The first method will remove only specific function callback while RemoveAllListeners will remove all event listeners attached to the callback. If you dont do this and try to assign new callback it will try to call old functions, and possibly might throw some errors.

Comment: Hope this resolves your problem. Always remember if you see callback functions in any class in unity like the above it should have method to add/update at runtime. So next time you can check how to use add/update/remove listeners in forums. Hope this helps :). If it works mark it answer and close the question.

Comment: Will definitely do that.

Comment: How do I close a question? :D

Comment: You marked it as answer so its ok. No need to do anything more. I really don't like all those questions with no marked answers. It kind of gets on my nerves even though many will have correct answers but OP wont close the question with marking answer lol.

Comment: That’s true, if someone helps you, you should at least mark it as answer as a „thankyou“.